# Auto complete not working on Fedora

Tags: bash, systemd, autocomplete

I am using Fedora 25. Seem the autocomplete on terminal using tab key is not working..

For example, I got this message when I want autocomplete my command:

> sudo systemctl start httpd.ser**Unit apparmor.service could not be
>   found**.

I check the systemD state and found this

```
$ sudo systemctl --state=not-found --all
  UNIT                            LOAD      ACTIVE   SUB  DESCRIPTION
● apparmor.service                not-found inactive dead apparmor.service
● fedora-autorelabel-mark.service not-found inactive dead fedora-autorelabel-mark.service
● fedora-autorelabel.service      not-found inactive dead fedora-autorelabel.service
● ip6tables.service               not-found inactive dead ip6tables.service
● ipset.service                   not-found inactive dead ipset.service
● iptables.service                not-found inactive dead iptables.service
● libvirt-guests.service          not-found inactive dead libvirt-guests.service
● lvm2-activation-early.service   not-found inactive dead lvm2-activation-early.service
● lvm2-activation.service         not-found inactive dead lvm2-activation.service
● nfs-secure-server.service       not-found inactive dead nfs-secure-server.service
● ntpd.service                    not-found inactive dead ntpd.service
● ntpdate.service                 not-found inactive dead ntpdate.service
● plymouth-quit-wait.service      not-found inactive dead plymouth-quit-wait.service
● plymouth-quit.service           not-found inactive dead plymouth-quit.service
● plymouth-read-write.service     not-found inactive dead plymouth-read-write.service
● plymouth-start.service          not-found inactive dead plymouth-start.service
● rpc-svcgssd.service             not-found inactive dead rpc-svcgssd.service
● sntp.service                    not-found inactive dead sntp.service
● syslog.service                  not-found inactive dead syslog.service
● ypbind.service                  not-found inactive dead ypbind.service
● syslog.target                   not-found inactive dead syslog.target

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

21 loaded units listed.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

Do anyone know how to fix this problem? Should I sent report to bug tracker?

Answer (score 2):

Found out this already reported on Redhat bug tracker
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1416588

It already fixed in rawhide. Not yet on Fedora 25.